# Get XPath of selected text using window.getSelection in javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript, dom

I am developing a highlighter chrome extension. It highlights and removes highlights without a problem. But I wanna save those highlights in storage and I need a path for each highlight. I can get the dom path of the element which is highlighted, but it's not enough. I also need a text node path for the text.

For more clarification:
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f1xtn.png)
Assume those words are highlighted, How could I find the path of each highlighted item? As you see all of those are in the same parent element *(div.max-w-3xl)*;

This is my highlight code:

```
      const selection = window.getSelection();
      const selectionRange = selection.getRangeAt(0);
      const id = nanoid();
      const mark = document.createElement("mark");
      const selectionIndexes = [
        selectionRange.startOffset,
        selectionRange.endOffset,
      ];

      mark.textContent = selection.toString();
      mark.dataset.highlightId = id;
      mark.classList.add("highlight");

      selectionRange.deleteContents();
      selectionRange.insertNode(mark);

      console.log(
        getElementPath(selectionRange.commonAncestorContainer as Element),
        selectionIndexes
      );
```

**getElementPath function:**

```
const getElementPath = (element): string => {
  let nodeName = element.nodeName.toLowerCase();
  if (element === document.body) return "body";
  if (element.id) nodeName += "#" + element.id;
  else if (element.classList.length)
    nodeName += "." + [...element.classList].join(".");
  return getElementPath(element.parentNode) + " " + nodeName;
};
```

**The log result:**

*body div.bg-base-100.drawer.drawer-mobile div.drawer-content div.px-6.xl:pr-2.pb-16 div.flex.flex-col-reverse.justify-between.gap-6.xl:flex-row div.prose.w-full.max-w-4xl.flex-grow div.max-w-3xl (2) [8, 10]*